# KineticJS: setFill not working

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Here's the gist of it: I have a getColor method, and a setColor method.

1. getColor updates a global pointer `color_obj` to the current object.
2. setColor uses that pointer to change the color of the object.

Problem is, it only draws it as black.

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/EbvH7/3/

and the source - html:

```
<html>
<!--- Click the square box to get its color. 
    Then change the color and hit set.
    For some reason it draws the color black only....   -->

<head>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/v4.2.0/kinetic-v4.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jscolor.com/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>

<script>
var stage;                              //canvas
var layer_frame = new Kinetic.Layer();  //Blue frame holder
var color_obj;     //global pointer to object to be colored. 

function getColor(obj) {
    color_obj = obj;    //set global pointer

    var fill = '"'+color_obj.getFill()+'"';
    var name = color_obj.getName();

    document.getElementById('color_pick').color.fromString(fill);
    document.getElementById('colorname_obj').innerHTML = name;

}

function setColor(){
    //Use global pointer
    var fill = document.getElementById('color_pick').color;
    var name = document.getElementById('colorname_obj').innerHTML;


    color_obj.setFill('"'+fill+'"'); 
    color_obj.setName(name);

    stage.draw()
}    


function setup() {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400, height: 400
    });

    var frame_area = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100, y: 100, opacity: 1,
        width: 30, height: 30,
        fill: 'a7cccb', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2,
        name: 'blue_box'
    });

    frame_area.on('click', function() {
        getColor(this)
    });


    // add the layer to the stage
    layer_frame.add(frame_area);
    stage.add(layer_frame);

    stage.draw();    

};


</script>
</head>

<body onload="setup()">
<!--Canvas--->
<div id="container"></div>

<!--Panels-->
<div id="panel_left">
<!--- C O L O R   B O X -->
    <div id="colorbox">
        <h7 id="colorname_obj" >None</h7><br/>
        <input class="color" id="color_pick" style="width:50%" value="000000" >
        <input type="button" id="color_set" value="Set" onclick="setColor()" >
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

and css:

```
#panel_left {
   position:absolute;
   top:30px; left:30px;
   width:100px; background-color:red;
}

#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px; left:130px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%; height:50%;    
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('color_pick').color` returns a hex-code. So, if you intend to use it to set the fill, you need to prefix it with '#'. So, you have to do `color_obj.setFill('#'+fill);`. But that won't work until you do `color_obj = frame_area;` in `setup`. Otherwise, `color_obj` is undefined until a `click` event is fired.

Comment: works -- thank you so much. Is there any way I can give you more credit?

Answer (score 0):

Also, new in 4.3.0

big changes to Kinetic.Text shape. Rectangle component has been removed to simplify the API. textFill is now fill, textStroke is now stroke, textStrokeWidth is now strokeWidth, and textShadow is now shadow. If you want to have a rectangle behind the text, you need to group the text with a Kinetic.Rect shape. Text fontSize units are now in pixels (used to be in points). The lineHeight attr is now defaulted to 1 (used to be defaulted to 1.2).